# Rails' ActiveRecord exposes race conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, race-condition

Assume I have this very simple controller:

```
class CountersController
  def inc
    c = Counter.find(1)
    c.value += 1
    c.save!
  end
end
```

If two clients access `inc` method at the same time, is it possible that `c.value` only increases by 1? If so, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you do it like this:

```
def inc
  c = Counter.find(1)
    c.with_lock do
      c.value += 1
      c.save!
    end
  end
end
```

It will lock the row in the database as it updates.

Answer (score 0):

its better to do the increment in the database like this:

```
Counter.update_counters id, :value => amount to increment
```

so for you its like this

```
Counter.update_counters 1, :value => 1
```

which creates to following SQL statement

```
UPDATE "counters" SET "value" = COALESCE("value", 0) + 1 WHERE "counters"."id" = 1
```

Comment: you can only solve this by having the database handle this, because its locking the row during the update and my code shows how to put this in the database